# how to check the mysql connectivity in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

In my rails app i need to write a ruby script which the admins use to check the status of the application. i need to check the connectivity of mysql connection, like the app is connected to the DB or not.. How do i do this . this ruby script i ll place in the script directory..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`connected?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002372) method to see whether an ActiveRecord has a connection to the database.

Answer (score 1):

(1)  You can try to establish a manual connection by using [Mysql.real_connect](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-real-connect.html):

```
Mysql.real_connect("localhost", "testuser", "testpass", "test")
```

See this [link](http://www.tm-research.com/manuals/databases/mysql/Using-the-Ruby-MySQL-Module.html) for further information.

(2) Another possibility (maybe the better one) is using [ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) directly:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => "mysql",
  :host     => "localhost",
  :username => "myuser",
  :password => "mypass",
  :database => "somedatabase"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connected?
```

Also you can get the current configuration like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config()
```

[All the related commands are available here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling.html)